# interface extends comparable

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: What is the difference between implementing Comparable and Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator)

Difference between comparable interface and comparator interface and where to use?example?

Comment: Did you try finding this by yourself? What point are you stuck at?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Comparable` makes an object intrinsically comparable to other objects.

`Comparator` allows to implement external comparison logic, which can be applied to objects that are not `Comparable`, or that require different logic from their default comparison logic.

For example, you have `Collections.sort(list)`, which can sort only lists of objects that implement `Comparable`, while there is another method - `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`, by which you can sort any list.

Answer (score 0):

In conceptual sense, a Comparator is the "comparison operator", i.e. the logic, used to determine whether a Comparable is greater/lesser than another Comparable.

PS: I'm using the term "operator" in comparison operator rather loosely; as they're not operator as in having symbols (e.g. <) syntactically assigned to the operations.

In a more practical sense, a Comparable allows an Object to determine how to compare itself with another Object. While Comparator allows the programmer to determine how to compare two Objects.