# Java how to order a List in alphabetical order by one of its elements

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, twitter4j

I am attempting to add in a users friend list into my application so that they can quickly find people that they follow on twitter, currently I am able to do this but the results come back based on the most recent people that the user followed but not in alphabetical order which is what I want, is there a way that I can essentially take a list of lists and sort the entire list based one one specific element in the list?

EDIT: sorry totally forgot to add in my code, my apologies

```
long cursor = -1;
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            PagableResponseList<User> userGroups = null;
            do {
                userGroups = twitter.getFriendsList(app.getUserId(), cursor);
                for (User user : userGroups) {
                    users.add(user);
                }
            } while ((cursor = userGroups.getNextCursor()) != 0);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109890/android-java-how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-certain-value-within-the-object

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method. You will have to create a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this, but there are many available tutorials on this.
What you basically do is you subclass the Comparator to compare two `User` objects, and return a result based on the name. If the names are Strings, you can just return `user1.name.compareTo(user2.name);`, since Strings already have a compare-method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your List to a Set

```
Set<User> users = new TreeSet<User>();
```

This assumes that your `User`s are unique.

You may have to wrap the `User` class with your own class so you can write your own `Comparator`.