# Android Sorting Json data

Tags: java, android, json

I am new. I'm trying to sorting the data that I get from json parse,but nothing work.
Not even an error.
I try [How to Sort JSON Array from JSON Objects in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423526/how-to-sort-json-array-from-json-objects-in-android)

I don't know what's wrong with my code, because there's no error.
But there's a warning "Implicitly using the default locale is common source of bugs: Use toLowerCase(Locale) instead" on here

```
return (lhs.getString("item_name").toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.getString("item_name").toLowerCase()));
```

Is there anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Here's my java code

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < foods.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                    JSONObject c = foods.getJSONObject(i);

                    if(c.getString("category_id").equals("1")) {
                        // Adding to array. Only items with category_id = 1 will be sorted.
                        array.add(foods.getJSONObject(i));  // This line is important

                        String item_id = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ITEM_ID, item_id);  

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        foodslist.add(contact);

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
                Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try {
                            return (lhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).compareTo(rhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
          }      
        else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And here's my Json data

```
[{"id":"201","category_id":"0","category_name":null,"item_name":"","description":"","address":"","area":""}
```

Thanks before.

Comment: That is just a warning. You can use @suppresswarnings to avoid it if you feel uncomfortable, provided your app is not meant for multi languages

Answer (score 0):

That is just a warning.

1. You can use @SuppressWarnings to avoid it if you feel uncomfortable, provided your app is not meant for multi languages
   OR
2. You can use : `toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());` to avoid this warning. Make sure to import `import java.util.Locale;`

---

**EDIT**

Hope below code will help you:

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
     JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if(c.getString("category_id").equals("1")
    {
         // Adding to array. Only items with category_id = 1 will be sorted.
         array.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));  // This line is important

         // All other stuff here.....
          String item_id = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);
                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ITEM_ID, item_id);
                        // adding contact to contact list
                        foodslist.add(contact);
    }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            return (lhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).compareTo(rhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT AGAIN**

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < foods.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        try {
                        JSONObject c = foods.getJSONObject(i);

                        if(c.getString("category_id").equals("1")) {
                            // Adding to array. Only items with category_id = 1 will be sorted.
                            array.add(foods.getJSONObject(i));  // This line is important

                            String item_id = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);

                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put(TAG_ITEM_ID, item_id);  

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            foodslist.add(contact);
                        } // End of if c.getstring

                        } // End of inner try
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } // End of inner catch
                     } // End of for loop
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            try {
                                return (lhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).compareTo(rhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return 0;
                            }
                        }
                    });

            } // End  of if jsonstr
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
```

Comment: thanks, but do you know why the sorting is not working?

Comment: Its because your code is not the same as the source you are trying with. You have declared `array`, but not assigned any value to it anywhere in your code.

Comment: In the original post, note the line `array.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));` This is necessary for sorting. In your code, this line is missing.

Comment: i'm trying to do what you said, but there's an error "array cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add add try { on my code :D
But the ask me to add "finally" to complete blockstatements.

Comment: What finally? The usual construct for finally is `try - catch - finally`. But in your case, I don't think it is necessary! Finally related docs are here : <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html>

Comment: You can check it on my question.I already edit my code.
The error is on "}" right before the last else

Comment: @Matthew: Refer edit again section. The braces are not closed properly. I have commented against each close brace for your understanding.

Comment: Ok, I try the code that you gave. and there's a new error "array cannot be resolved" in this line                     Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {. I think because its not in if statement

Comment: i am trying to add catch before else statement.
}
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
                    
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

And I got error "Unreachable catch block for JSONException.
It suggest to remove it, but when I remove it, I got an error on log cat.

Comment: Did you try the code i have provided in EDIT AGAIN section? The open and close braces are correct in that section. If you want, try changing the `JSONException e` to only `Exception e`

Comment: Yes, i already try it and I got two errors.
First on this line                  Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {. It said "array cannot be resolved to a variable".
Second on else line. "Sintax error, { expected"

Comment: @Matthew: I get it, the collections.sort should be inside the if part. I have re-edited my answer in the edit again part. Check now.

Comment: I don't get it why, Its looks perfect but still there is an error about that array variable.
Its gone if I put the collection.sort inside the outer try part. But it'll show another error on JSONException.

Comment: @Matthew: You seem to have a very basic issue. Note: Any if should have a corresponding else and any try should have a corresponding catch. Please go thru basic java documentations to sort this error!

Comment: Once solved, accept as answer for the time spent and answer provided!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
.toLowerCase().
```

change it like this

```
.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
```

It will help.

and also check for Null in variables and >0 check for arrays.