# Android : Sorting of JSON Data obtained or taken by making rest call

Tags: android

My question is that i have to display my data which is fetched from JSON file ,the json file is below. But i want the data to be in sorted form after getting from JSON file i.e after the rest call when data is obtained from controller in viewmodel,so that i can directly display it on the View Class. which has cardviews.

```
{
 "employeeList":[
    {
      "employeeName": "aaaa",
      "employeeStatus": "Trainee",
      "company": "IBM",
      "mobile": "894996662"
   },
   {
      "employeeName": "bbbb",
      "employeeStatus": "Fellowship",
      "company": "Wipro",
      "mobile": "9876000021"
   },
   {
      "employeeName": "cccc",
      "employeeStatus": "Fellowship",
      "company": "CGI",
      "mobile": "9876000021"
   },
   {
      "employeeName": "cccc",
      "employeeStatus": "Fellowship",
      "company": "CGI",
      "mobile": "9876000021"
   }
  ]
}
```

And the .java file is below,were i have not done the sorting.I need the help,Thank you.

```
try {
                    //As the data in rest call contained in JSONObject inside that JSONArray and inside
                    //JSONArray JSONObject is there ,Hence to get the data and set to the Model Class
                    //Creating JSON Object and obtained the data in bytes
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(bytes));
                    Log.i("json object", "employeeList: ");
                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("employeeList");
                        Log.i("json Array", "employeeList: " + jsonArray.length());
                        //Creating the object of modelClass

                        if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject childObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                //Through the object of model Class the obtained data is set to the
                                //Model class
                                EnggFragModel enggFragModel = new EnggFragModel();

                                enggFragModel.setImageurl(childObject.getString("imageUrl"));
                                Log.i("image", "employeeData: "+childObject.getString("imageUrl"));
                                enggFragModel.setEmployeeName(childObject.getString("employeeName"));
                                enggFragModel.setEmployeeStatus(childObject.getString("employeeStatus"));
                                enggFragModel.setCompany(childObject.getString("company"));
                                enggFragModel.setEmployeeMobile(childObject.getString("mobile"));
                                enggFragModel.setEmployeeEmail(childObject.getString("emailId"));
                                enggFragModel.setEngineerID(childObject.getString("engineerId"));
                                Log.i("EngineerId", "employeeData: " + childObject.getString("engineerId"));
                                enggArrayList.add(enggFragModel);
                            }
                            enggViewModelInterface.enggViewMInterface(enggArrayList);
                            Log.i("Employee", "employeeList: " + enggArrayList);
                        }

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("Employee", "employeeList: ");
```

Comment: Read about Comparators. Refer this link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to take JSONArray "employeeList" convert it to ArrayList of JSONObject and sort it, using **Collections**.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
        array.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            return (lhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.getString("Name").toLowerCase()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

[Here is original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423893/3563511)