# How to Search from custom Listview using custom Filter

Tags: android, json, listview, search

I am making an application is which I'm populating custom listview data from JSON which is working totally fine no Issues.
i want to implement search feature in my listview using Edittext
I follow this [tutorial](http://tech-papers.org/android-listview-search-using-filter/).

I completed all the steps but when i write something in my Edittext nothing shows in list and even after removing listview will not populate again.

I don't want to get data everytime from JSON.

Please Help me with this.

Here is my Code

Custom Adapter Class Code

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<CategoryData> CategoryList = new ArrayList<CategoryData>();
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private ArrayList<CategoryData> mlist;
private Context context;

public CategoryAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<CategoryData> mlist) {
    this.context = c;
    this.CategoryList = mlist;
    this.mlist = mlist;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mlist.addAll(mlist);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_category,
                parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_best = (LetterSpacing) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_best);
        holder.tv_title = (LetterSpacing) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        holder.tv_votes = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_votes);
        holder.tv_dish = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dish);
        holder.tv_restaurant = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurant);
        holder.img_logo = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    CategoryData categoryData = mlist.get(position);
    holder.tv_best.setSpacing(-6f);
    holder.tv_best.setText("Best");
    holder.tv_title.setSpacing(-6f);
    holder.tv_title.setText(categoryData.bestName);
    holder.tv_votes.setText(categoryData.bestVotes);
    holder.tv_dish.setText(categoryData.bestDishes);
    holder.tv_restaurant.setText(categoryData.bestRestaurant);
    // Picasso.with(context).load(categoryData.logo).into(holder.img_logo);
    holder.mCity = categoryData.City;
    String imageUrl = categoryData.bestRetaurantLogo;
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.img_logo);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemRankActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", holder.tv_title.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("category", holder.tv_dish.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("city", holder.mCity);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    LetterSpacing tv_best;
    LetterSpacing tv_title;
    TextView tv_votes;
    TextView tv_dish;
    TextView tv_restaurant;
    ImageView img_logo;
    String mCity;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {

    CategoryList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        CategoryList.addAll(mlist);
    } else {
        for (CategoryData Wd : mlist) {
            if (Wd.bestName.equals(charText)) {
                CategoryList.add(Wd);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}}
```

My Code in MainActivity for textchanging

```
et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = et_search.getText().toString();
            adapter.filter(text);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Please Help me with this I am stuck in this problem from last 2 days.

Comment: Have a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109990/1061944. What you need to do is to implement a compareable to sort your list view.

Comment: use `adapter.filter(s.toString);` instead of `adapter.filter(text);`

Comment: @Rustam its not working

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I am getting data from json and have an adapter class can you please explain where and how i can  implement compareable to get search data from listview

Comment: I would suggest to create a loop with listview length and scan every text string as position....and populate the list view..

Comment: @Mohit that would be the worst thing to do.

Comment: @AsadMehmood the best way to learn is to learn by doing, here is the [GIST](https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308) which is doing the same thing you are trying to do. have a look

Comment: I solved my problem by making another webserivce for search in which i pass the search string with url and it gives me the searched JSON which i populate on my arraylist
this is easy and best way to this if your data is coming from some server side rather then doing it locally