# How can i sort the ListView according to the phone number?

Tags: android, json, sorting, collections

I have a list of user with phone number. I have one menu to sort the list according to phone number? I tried using the Collection.sort() method but is is not working as i expected.
The json respose of user is :-

```
  {  
     "results":[  
        {  
           "name":{  
              "title":"mrs",
              "first":"hayley",
              "last":"moore"
           },
           "email":"hayley.moore@example.com",
           "dob":{  
              "date":"1965-10-21T18:13:17Z",
              "age":52
           },
           "phone":"(852)-247-7958",
           "picture":{  
              "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/26.jpg",
              "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/26.jpg",
              "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/26.jpg"
           }
        },
        {},
        .
        .
     ]
  }
```

Comment: You can check the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109890/android-java-how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-certain-value-within-the-object

Comment: Advise : When someone edit your bad formatted json to human readable form, do not revert it to one single line non readable form. No one is that free to navigate through your json which is not formatted properly.

Comment: @ Zankrut sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for sort your list on the criteria of Phone Number.

Put your model in place of user.

put your field getter in place of getPhoneNum.

```
 Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
    return u1.getValue().replace("(","").compareTo(u2.getValue().replace("(",""));
  }
});
```

Comment: i already use thiks method

Comment: Share your code with model code !

Comment: private class EventDetailsSortByMobile implements java.util.Comparator<UserModel> {
        @Override
        public int compare(UserModel customerEvents1, UserModel customerEvents2) {
            String phone1, phone2;
            phone1 = customerEvents1.getPhone().toLowerCase().trim();
            phone2 = customerEvents2.getPhone().toLowerCase().trim();
            return phone1.compareTo(phone2);
        }
    }

Comment: I have Updated my answer check,
Just replace place in return statement

Comment: it partially  sort not completely

Comment: give me all telephone numbers you are putting ?

Comment: It is sorting on area code i.e (852),(021)

Comment: number are:--0880-2810143
04-372-336
05-901-193
03-09-25-36-57
(612)-289-5271
0570-7311775
906-919-143
04-76-30-43-12
949-028-609
72839489
0118069 376 7535
0704-4505192
(746)-096-1723
18718618
(278)-489-7144
(308)-139-4904
0047-7529059
980-484-880
933-996-035
(474)-358-8458
(497)-188-6116
097-63794037

Comment: for number without area code...how can i short for that?

Comment: try now, return statement updated.

Comment: Thank you so much  bro  you save my life...again thankyou

Comment: Good to here it from you :), Please mark this answer as right.