# Comparable and Comparator

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: What is the difference between implementing Comparable and Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator)
>   [When to use Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator)

what's the difference between comparable and comparator interface ?
can someone explain me by providing an **corresponding example** ?

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1440134/839527 This previous question will be help you

Comment: http://jagadeeshm.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/java-difference-between-comparable-and-comparator-interface/ http://www.javabeat.net/qna/633-difference-between-comparable-interface-and-c/ http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t141190-difference-between-comparator-and-comparable-interface.html ... http://apachejava.blogspot.com/2010/10/difference-between-comparable-and.html Take your pick! I have more :)

Answer (score 3):

THis is what the rule of the thumb:

1. implement `Comparable` interface to provide natural ordering.
2. Use `Comparator`, to sort a collection of objects based on the criteria you wished for.

so you have

*Note*: The following code is just for illustration purpose, may not compile.

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

   public int age;
   public String name;

   //defined natural ordering is by name
   public int compareTo(Stundent that){
      return this.name.compareTo(that.name);
   }
}

public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Student>{
   int compare(Student s, Student t){
      return s.age - t.age;
   }
}
```

Now, If you have a List of `Student`, say, `studentList`, you can use the following

```
Collections.sort(studentList); //sorts by natural ordering; by name
Collections.sort(studentList, new AgeComparator()); //sorts by age
```

Answer (score 0):

**From the Java Documentation on [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)**:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's *natural ordering*, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its *natural comparison method*.

In other words, a class that implements `Comparable` is capable of comparing itself to other objects of the same kind.

**From the Java documentation on [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)**:

> A comparison function, which imposes a `total ordering` on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort`) to allow precise control over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order of certain data structures (such as `sorted sets` or `sorted maps`), or to provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a `natural ordering`.

A class that implements `Comparator` is capable of comparing other objects with each other.

Answer (score 0):

An object which has the type `Comparable<T>` is **naturally ordered** with respect to `T`. Given a `T that`, it determines the relation (`<`, `=`, or `>`) between `this` and `that`.

A `Comparator<T>` is an **ordering** of `T`. Given two `T`s, it determines their relation (`<`, `=`, or `>`).

An example of a naturally ordered type is `Integer`. The natural order of integers is {`-MAX_VALUE`, ..., `-1`, `0`, `1`, ..., `MAX_VALUE`}. A type can only have one natural order, partly because the concept of a natural order entails that it is unique, and partly because a single class can't have multiple implementations of `Comperable.compareTo`.

On the other hand, there can be several meaningful `Comparator`s for a single type. For example, `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` is a `Comparator<String>` which ignores case.