# When printing list it is gibberish

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Object default toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/java-object-default-tostring)

Why is it when I print my List from filereader it is [myServiceOrder@3bc1cac, myServiceOrder@32fe621e, myServiceOrder@5adbb9b9, myServiceOrder@f7e4f49, myServiceOrder@2d874991, myServiceOrder@ceee5f1, myServiceOrder@183a37d9]

```
public class myServiceOrder implements ServiceOrder, Comparable<myServiceOrder>{

private int number=0;
private String ownerName="";
private String make="";
private String model="";
private int year=0;

public myServiceOrder(int number, String ownerName, String make, String model,  int year) {
    this.number=number;
    this.ownerName=ownerName;
    this.make=make;
    this.model=model;
    this.year=year;
}

public myServiceOrder() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void setOrderNum(int orderNumber) {
    number=orderNumber;
}

@Override
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year=year;
}

@Override
public void setOwner(String ownerName) {
    this.ownerName=ownerName;
}

@Override
public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make=make;
}

@Override
public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model=model;

}

@Override
public String getOwner() {
    return ownerName;
}

@Override
public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

@Override
public String getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return  model;
}

@Override
public int getOrderNum() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return number;
}

@Override
public int getYear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return year;
}

@Override
public String getMakeModelYear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return make+ " "+ model+ " "+ year+ " ";
}

@Override
public boolean equals(ServiceOrder otherServiceOrder) {
        if (getOrderNum()==otherServiceOrder.getOrderNum())
            return true;
        else
    return false;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ServiceOrder otherServiceOrder, int key) {
    int comparisonResult=0;
    if(key==1)
    {
        if(getOrderNum()< otherServiceOrder.getOrderNum())
            comparisonResult= -1;
        if(getOrderNum()== otherServiceOrder.getOrderNum())
            comparisonResult= 0;
        if(getOrderNum()> otherServiceOrder.getOrderNum())
            comparisonResult= 1;
    }
        else if(key==2)
        {
            comparisonResult = getOwner().compareTo(otherServiceOrder.getOwner());                      
        }

        else if(key==3)
        {
         comparisonResult = getOwner().compareTo(otherServiceOrder.getOwner());
        }
    return comparisonResult;

}

@Override
public int compareTo(myServiceOrder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class List extends LinkedList<myServiceOrder> {
private static  LinkedList<myServiceOrder> newList = new LinkedList();

 public  void  Print() throws Exception
 {
     System.out.println(newList);
 }
public   LinkedList<myServiceOrder> createServiceOrder(File inFile) throws Exception {
    int number=0;
     String ownerName="";
     String make="";
     String model="";
     int year=0;
     myServiceOrder serviceList = new myServiceOrder();    
        Scanner fileScan=new Scanner(inFile);
            while (fileScan.hasNext())
            {
                String ignore;

                number = fileScan.nextInt();
                //System.out.println(number);
                ignore = fileScan.nextLine(); // ignore the newline
                ownerName = fileScan.nextLine();
            //  System.out.println(ownerName);
                make = fileScan.nextLine();
        //      System.out.println(make);
                model = fileScan.nextLine();
            //  System.out.println(model);
                year = fileScan.nextInt();
        //      System.out.println(year);
                ignore = fileScan.nextLine(); // ignore the newline
                  serviceList = new myServiceOrder( number,  ownerName,  make,        model,  year);         
                  newList.add(serviceList);

            }
        fileScan.close();


     //   System.out.println(newList.viewAll());
        return newList; 
    }


}
```

Ok I see, my was I dense. I also have a second question: I have to sort the list three different ways depending in my GUI what option I select, I assume that I implement `Comparable`, but in my `compareTo` interface it is `compareTo(Object o, int key)`. How can I use that key if the sort method is just Object o. Should I try using a `Comparator`?  if my `key=1` how can I tell it to sort that way in my List class?

Comment: The gibberish is the `hashcode` of the object. To get more friendly printouts, you need to override the `toString()` method in your class.

Comment: It would have been better to pay closer attention to formatting so that the second question wasn't hidden by the code formatting =_=

Answer (score 7):

Classic case of a missing override of the toString() method in your myServiceOrder class.

Take a look [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) for examples in implementation. [This page](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/08/overriding-the-tostring-method-in-object-class/) and [Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657173/1708136) give explanations as to *why* you need to override toString().

Argh didn't see your second question until now when it's very late:

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-and-comparator) on the differences between using the `Comparable` interface vs using the `Comparator` interface.

Answer (score 3):

How would Java know how you want myService objects to be printed? You can tell it by overriding toString:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "myServiceObject#" + number + "[" + ownername + ", " + make + ", " + model + ", " + year + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What gets printed is actually the hashcode of the object you print without overriding toString method.. Now since you're printing `LinkedList`, you can't do that.. Rather you can iterate over the list and print individual element: -

```
public  void  Print() throws Exception
 {
    for (myServiceOrder so: newList) {
         System.out.println(so)
    }
 }
```

Now, since `serviceOrder` is itself an object.. You would need to override your `toString()` in that class..

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.ownerName + this.make + "[" +  this.model + " - " + String.valueOf(this.year) + "]";            
}
```

Comment: Printing a `LinkedList` object automatically iterates over the objects in the list. In fact, this happens in the `LinkedList.toString()` method.

Comment: @Code-Guru.. Yeah that is true.. I just used this way to print without that square bracket at the end `[`, and `]`.. And I don't think this deserves a down-vote..

Comment: I'm still a little confused, in myServiceOrder class what would my toString look like and then how could I print that

Comment: You can add any variable to your return value, that you want to print, and format it in whatever way you want.. That is why `toString()` is overrided..

Comment: `toString()` method is automatically invoked when you print an instance of that class.. And the string returned from `toString()` is printed..

Comment: Ok I see, my was I dense.  I also got a second question,  I have to sort the list 3 differant ways depending in my GUI what option I select,  I assume that I implement Comparable, but in my comparto inter face it is compareTo(Object o, int key) how can I use that key if the sort method is just Object o.  Should I try comparator?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(newList);
```

This automatically calls the `toString()` method of the `LinkedList` class which in turn calls `toString()` on each of the references in the list (your `ServiceOrder` objects, in this case). Since you have not provided your own `toString()` method, the default one in `Object` is used. This gives the funny output `myServiceOrder@3bc1cac` which is Java's default way of printing a reference variable. If you wish to see something else, you need to tell Java how to do this by implementing `toString()` in your `ServiceOrder` class.