# Design decision: Convert code to display String

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm developing a project with domain objects that contains quite a few fields. The fields only store **numbers** as codes or IDs.

To display these domain objects, I have to write some logic to convert the codes to display labels.

Now, with my most straightforward thoughts, **I'd just write a utility class to do the conversion.**

However, since this should be a very common cases, I am just wondering is there any better practice for doing this kind of job? (in a more object-oriented way)

Is there any design pattens for this context?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you explain why you voted down this question without providing any useful information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the concept of utility classes. The utility closet is where you dump anything you don't have a label for. You do have a label for this action. `Serializer` or `Labeler`.

Create an interface `Serializer` or `Labeler` or whatever, and implement it however many times as needed (if there are domain objects which don't serialize the same, or if you need extra functionality).

---

Another approach would be to have your domain object serialize themselves, in which case any serializable object can implement a `Serializable` interface, and your rendering function can accept only `Serializable` objects.

Similar to the **[comparable vs comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/when-should-a-class-be-comparable-and-or-comparator)** debate.

Comment: thanks for ur comment! As to your suggestion, could it also be used in the case where we want to label the IDs separately? For example, for a class Person with occupation & sex, i'd like to convert occupation 0 to "Teachers", 1 to "Engineers", 2 to "Solders", and convert sex 0 to "Female", 1 to "Male".

Comment: The reason i'm asking this is because Serializable sounds like a way to dump the whole object to a String representation I want. But what I want is a more delicate way to convert each field as needed

Answer (score 0):

Almost sounds like a "foreign key" or a "dictionary" or a "map".
Mapping a "occupation" of "0" to "Teacher".
Mapping a "sex" of "0" to "Female".

If you have enough data, you could just dump it into a database ... perform a lookup, and dump the result:

```
field-name, value, text 
"occupation", 0, "Teacher"
"occupation", 1,"Engineer" 
"sex", 0, "Female"
```

Then, you can "easily" (ha ha) add more and more to the database table as you need to.

Of course there are "many ways to skin a cat" ... you could just have a code file that has a dictionary/map in it to do the exact same lookup.  You can "easily" (ha ha) add more to the code file.