# Java Student Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to create class SorterDemo with following mechanisms.

**sortDouble** - `sort array of double variables.`

**sortString** - `sort given String value in alphabetical manner.`

**sortStudent** - `sort array of Student objects based on marks.`

I need to sort these functions into single main class **SorterDemo**
Since I'm using comparator operator, at the time of using it in `SorterDemo` class, it's not allowing me to change.

Comment: Please be more specific: post the exact error message or exception stack trace (and tell us to which line that matches in your source code). In other words: please visit the help center and learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: It's Arrays.sort(arr) not Array.sort(arr)

Comment: And also instead of this: public String sortString(String str){
    String s=str;
    char[] arr=s.toCharArray();
    Array.sort(arr);
    String str=String.copyValueOf(arr);
    return str;
    }  you can just say "char[] arr = str.toCharArray(); and then after sort str = String.copyValueOf(arr) return str; You are creating two uneccessary strings right there.

Comment: on `sort str = String.copyValueOf(arr);` its saying `Multiple markers at this line
 - Duplicate local variable 
  str
 - sort cannot be resolved 
  to a type`

Comment: @Jägermeister At lline `Student[] stud=new Student[5];` and  ` stud[i]=new Student(rollno,name,mk);` The error is `Student[] stud=new Student[5];`. 
 it's asking to create the  `class Student` but I have already created the class.

Comment: are you talking about the code in the question or the code in your source file ?

Comment: @niceman I have updated the code. It works fine now. Just need to implement all those functions into single main class `SorterDemo`. Thanks.

Comment: @niceman Can you please tell me an approach to do so? or simple example where `implement` opearator is used would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want them to be all inside `SorterDemo` class, well you can put `sortString` class and `sortStudent` class inside `SorterDemo` class as nested classes(you put `static` before them).

A better approach though is to have something like this :

```
Class SorterDemo
{      
    static void sortString(Student[] stud)
    {
        Arrays.sort(stud,Student.namecomparator);
    }
    static void sortStudent(Student[] stud)
    {
        Arrays.sort(stud,Student.markscomparator);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student student[] = new Student[3];



        // initializing unsorted double array
        double dArr[] = { 3.2, 1.2, 9.7, 6.2, 4.5 };
        // let us print all the elements available in list
        for (double number : dArr) {
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }

        // sorting array
        Arrays.sort(dArr);

        // let us print all the elements available in list
        System.out.println("The sorted double array is:");
        for (double number : dArr) {
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }

        student[0] = new Student();
        student[0].setName("Nick");
        student[0].setmarks(19);

        student[1] = new Student();
        student[1].setName("Helen");
        student[1].setmarks(12);

        student[2] = new Student();
        student[2].setName("Ross");
        student[2].setmarks(16);

        System.out.println("Order of students before sorting is: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(student[i].getName() + "\t" + student[i].getmarks());
        }

        sortStudent(student);
        System.out.println("Order of students after sorting by student marks is");

        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(student[i].getName() + "\t" + student[i].getmarks());
        }

        sortString(student);
        System.out.println("Order of students after sorting by student name is");

        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(student[i].getName() + "\t" + student[i].getmarks());
        }
    }
}
class Student
{
    static Comparator<Student> namecomparator=(s1,s2)->s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
    static Comparator<Student> markscomparator=(s1,s2)->Integer.compare(s1.getmarks(),s2.getmarks());
    //the rest of class 
}
```

As you can see We're defining two comparators as static fields of Student class, this talks like "we have two ways to compare Students : by name and by marks", we assign each comparator a lambda expression.

A lambda expression makes it easy to add implementations for interfaces that has only one method to implement(like Comparator) the syntax is like this : `(par1,par2,...)->expr` or `(par1,par2,...)->{//block of code}`, interface Runnable for example only has one method which is `void run` so we can define a Runnable variable like this : `Runnable r=()->{//implementation for run method}`.

Note that lambda expressions were introduced in java 8, in java 7 you use anonymous classes(classes without name) like this :

```
static Comparater<Student> namecomparator=new Comparator<Student>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1,Student s2)
    {
        return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
    }
};
```

lambda expressions or anonymous classes relieves us from defining classes just for purpose of implementing interfaces, you must use anonymous classes even in java 8 if the interface has more than one method to implement.

It is reasonable to define a named class that implements interface `A` only when that class has many things besides what `A` has, that's my opinion at least :).

### Note

There is `Comparable` interface, you can make Student class implement that interface, more on the difference between Comparable and Comparator can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/when-should-a-class-be-comparable-and-or-comparator)

Comment: Thanks. Source code updated. It's working fine. Just that I'm unable to call those static functions for printing. Tried `Arrays.sort(student, new sortStudent());` Similar for calling SortString().