# Comparable and Comaprator interfaces

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

It is generally said that comparator is used to have multiple sorting sequences of  collection of objects while comparable is used to have single sorting sequence.
What is the use of comparator interface in java when it is possible to have multiple sorting sequences using comparable interface?

```
import java.util.*;
enum CompareValue {RollNo, Marks;}
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    public int marks;
    public int rollNo;
    public static CompareValue comparator = CompareValue.RollNo;
    Student (int marks, int rollNo) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        switch (comparator) {
            case RollNo:
                return this.rollNo - s.rollNo;
            case Marks:
                return this.marks - s.marks;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Student s1 = new Student(59, 103);
        Student s2 = new Student(87, 102);
        Student s3 = new Student(78, 101);
        Student students[] = {s1, s2, s3};
        Arrays.sort(students);
        System.out.println("Student list sorted by rollno");
        for (Student s:students) {
            System.out.println(s.rollNo + " - " + s.marks);
        }
        Student.comparator = CompareValue.Marks;
        System.out.println("Student list sorted by marks");
        Arrays.sort(students);
        for (Student s:students) {
            System.out.println(s.rollNo + " - " + s.marks);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if this answers your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/when-should-a-class-be-comparable-and-or-comparator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should a class be Comparable and/or Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/when-should-a-class-be-comparable-and-or-comparator)

Comment: Your solution isn't thread safe. If you have two threads trying to sort different ways at the same time, it would throw an exception. You need to be very careful of mutable `static` fields, and as this is error prone it is often considered a hack.

Answer (score 1):

When your `compareTo` method has different behaviors based on the value of some `static` variable, you are basically introducing a global setting that controls the natural ordering of the `Student` class.

This could be confusing and counter intuitive to users of your class.

Besides, it makes the implementation of `compareTo` awkward, especially if you have more than two implementations, and each implementation depends on multiple instance variables.

`Comparator` is a much more suitable interface to supply multiple different comparisons for instances of the same class, each implementation having its own `compare()` logic.

Answer (score 0):

When you have objects that do not implement comparable, but you would like to sort a collection consisting them, you would either have to extend them just to sort your collection or provide a comparator that compares them even though they are not comparable.

Or you might want to compare sort those objects in a different manner then their natural sort.

Imagine such an example. 
String is an object that is comparable. Imagine you want to sort a collection of strings based on their hashCode instead of the string natural order. How would you do it without creating a comparator?

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown there is indeed multiple sort orders using `Comparable`, but don't you think it's too much boiler plate code? Let's say if you have added a new field to the class called `name`, and now you want to sort by name. You'd have to:

- add a new case to the enum
- add a new case to the `compareTo`.

Another disadvantage of using the approach you showed is that it is not necessarily clear what this means:

```
Arrays.sort(student);
```

You would have to look through your code and check what value you have set the `comparator`.

Also, if I were using your class and I want to sort by something else, I would have to create a `Comparator` anyway, because I can't edit your class.

But if you use `Comparator`, you solve all of these problems:

```
Arrays.sort(students, Comparator.comparing(Student::getName));
```

Therefore, `Comparable` is only useful when there is *one* natural order, like dates and times for example.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the Comparable and Comparator interfaces and what they mean, everything will be clear.

**Comparable:**

This is an internal property of a JAVA class i.e. it assumes that whenever one uses the internal **compareTo()** method, one is using it for the specified object.

```
public int compareTo(T o);
```

Therefore, in implementation of this method we use `this` which is the current object and compare it to some other object of same type. These can be treated as defaults or use for natural ordering.

Like 1 comes before 2 and so on. This is the natural ordering.

**Comparator:**

This is property which actually is not tightly bound to the Java class itself. Comparators are used to actually provide a method to be used by some other services (like `Collections.sort()`) for achieving a particular goal.

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);
```

By this we mean, You can have multiple Comparators, providing different ways of achieving different goals wherein the actual service can pick any two objects and compare them.

This can be used to provide custom ordering, like using some equation we can come up with an ordering where **f(1)** actually comes after **f(2)** and so on. This equation will likely be achieving some order which solves a use-case.